# Change the layout for a specific product

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, theme

I've taken over maintenance of a multi-site Magento store & need to create a new layout to be used on certain products. I know I can select a custom layout in the design tab of the Product Information page in the back-end. What I don't quite understand is how I make a new layout to appear in the drop-down list here. I've looked at tutorials but nothing really seems to cover this. Am I right in thinking that I need to create something like newlayout.phtml in the theme's layout folder?

Any help, tips, advice, or tutorials would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new layout handle to the design tab of products by creating a module with the following in it's config.xml

```
<global>
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <your_new_layout translate="label">
                <label>Your New Layout</label>
                <template>if/you/need/a/custom/template.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>your_new_layout </layout_handle>
            </your_new_layout>
        </layouts>
    </page>
</global>
```

Then this will be shown in the admin section under product->design->page layout and also under Cms->Design->Layout section